Applying percentile conditional formatting to selected rows only (via GAS)
In my testing, I have used the below to color code according to percentile all rows in column K
var rule1 = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
.whenFormulaSatisfied("=$K2>=percentile(K$2:K,0.9)")  
.setBackground("#c9daf8")
.setRanges([range1])
.build();
var rule2 = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
.whenFormulaSatisfied("=$K2>=percentile(K$2:K,0.75)")
.setBackground("#d9ead3")
.setRanges([range1])
.build();
var rule3 = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
.whenFormulaSatisfied("=$K2>percentile(K$2:K,0.1)")
.setBackground("#fce8b2")
.setRanges([range1])
.build();
var rule4 = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
.whenFormulaSatisfied("=$K2<=percentile(K$2:K,0.1)")
.setBackground("#dd7e6b")
.setRanges([range1])
.build();

Now I would like to give the option of color coding selected rows only via a button but I am unsure of the correct formula.
For example, if rows 8 - 15 where selected, should the formula not be
.whenFormulaSatisfied("=$K8>=percentile(K8:K15,0.75)")

Not sure what I am doing wrong, the above does color code but its wrong
Thanks

Would you be able to provide your sample sheet, with your initial output, and also your expected output so that we can further help you. You may use this to provide a markdown table (you may create one with the help of this link ) or an anonymous sample spreadsheet (using this link)

Please make a minimal reproducible example that can be copy/paste/run without changes to illustrate the issue.
